# Preventing page reload after form submit. e.preventDefault() and hidden iFrame not working

Tags: javascript, html

I have been stuck on this for some time, scavenging SO and Google for all of these answers, but none of them seem to prevent my problem. All I am trying to do is to prevent a page reload after uploading a file, as it resets the dynamic html I want to write after.

Here is the HTML:

```
<form id = "fileForm" action = "/upload" method = "post" enctype = "multipart/form-data" target = "hiddenIFrame">
    <iframe id = "hiddenIFrame" name = "hiddenIFrame" style = "display: none"></iframe>
    <input type = "file" id = "fileInput" name = "uploadFile" accept = ".txt"/>
</form>
```

Here is the JS:

```
document.getElementById("fileInput").onchange = function(e) {
    document.getElementById("fileForm").submit();
};
```

All that then does is call to my backend /upload express call which uploads it to the server which works fine, it just refreshes / reloads the page.

I have tried many different ways of going about this, and have no idea why this is not working.
Any help is appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried whether it makes a difference if the iframe is not set to `display:none`?

Comment: @CBroe I just made the iFrame visible, unfortunately after upload the page still refreshes.

Comment: That's weird. Normally in such a situation I'd ask what the browser console says, if there's any JS errors - but in that case, your form should rather not submit at all in the first place. Do you have a live example of this somewhere?

Comment: I currently do not have a live example but upon load and when uploading there are no errors. I am fairly new to web development so It may be something small, but there is not much code to go wrong with hah.

Comment: Have you tried return false?

Comment: @Dani I have, in all the functions hah. Where would you suggest I place the return.

Comment: After submit();

Answer (score 1):

This is not directly answering your question, but you can communicate with your server (upload the file) without submitting the form in the traditional way and then dynamically update your HTML based on how your upload went.

Read about https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX  and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

Comment: Thank you, I will take a look at these resources.

Comment: It's actually pretty simple, you prevent the default behaviour of the form from happening, and then you send the image to the server, the server processes it and will respond to your request (whether it saved the image or not), then, you update things in the page depending on the response you got. (display an error, display a preview of the image etc.)

Comment: And use jQuery if you can, despite all the hate it gets from vanilla JavaScript fan boys, it's easier, simpler and more practical through all the helpers and utility methods it provides. Vanilla JavaScript makes sense in particular scenarios, but in usual web development, it does not in most of the cases. The latest jQuery versions are pretty small in size and its stuff have been reviewed by thousands of people, resulting in better performing code, using vanilla JS will result in you writing your very own library, but less efficient, with no cross-browser support and error-prone.

Comment: _"What happens is correct"_ - why, based on what can you say that? The form targets the iframe, so why should submitting it cause the parent document to reload? Only way I could see that happening (with what we know so far), was some JS code in the response document, that navigates the parent window elsewhere.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, my bad. I've personally never used the iframe hack. :s And you are right about parent / iframe docs, but the iframe can change parent's location if they belong to the same origin or they are under CORS. Updated answer, don't want to misinform.